# Update SQLITE table

Tags: update, sqlite

I want to update my sqlite table and I use a request with conditionals my purpose is to set the name to the new value when the value is not null and keep the old value if the new value is null .
I would like anybody check my request to see if there is something wrong cause I'm getting errors

**The request below :**

```
UPDATE user SET name = CASE WHEN (? = NULL) THEN user.name ELSE ? END  WHERE ID=? ;
```

**The error I'm getting here**

```
SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: NOT NULL constraint failed: user.name
Emitted 'error' event on Statement instance at:
] {
  errno: 19,
  code: 'SQLITE_CONSTRAINT'
}
```

Comment: You have not told us what the errors are. And not read the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#isisnot).

Comment: I read it but it is not simple to understand for me so I did as I have understood

Comment: NULL means 'unknown'. If you compare some value with null `(? = NULL)` - what result this must give? we compare something and unknown something - the result is unknown, i.e. the result is NULL... which is always treated as FALSE. So ELSE variant is executed/calculated always...

Comment: But if instead of (?=NULL) I compare ( ? != NULL) it could permit me to have what I want ?

Comment: *if instead of (?=NULL) I compare ( ? != NULL)* then you again will obtain NULL treated as FALSE in any case. Or `IS [NOT] NULL`, or null-safe compare operator `<=>` (dependent by the logic).

Comment: Ok thank you . But when I try this it works UPDATE user 

SET name = CASE

WHEN ? != 'null' THEN ?

ELSE  name END

WHERE ID= ? ; why ?

Comment: You need to use `<expression> IS NULL` or `<expression> IS NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE user 
SET name = COALESCE(?, name) -- name to add if the value is not null
WHERE ID = ?                 -- id value of the record which must be updated
;
```

Comment: I tried your request but it doesn't work . This is what I want : **if ? is null keep old value and if ? not null change the old value**

Comment: That would then be `COALESCE(?, name)`

Comment: Right this time it works